# Parallel HTTP Connection in J2ME Midlet

Tags: java-me, midlet

Somebody know about possibility to establish in different threads of J2ME Midlet 2-3 parallel HTTP connections. I's looks possible but works unstable. Maybe somebody have more information about topic.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly worth a try and I believe this will work on some good phones but this is typically something that the JSR-118 Test Conformance Kit doesn't test for (as far as I can remember) so it could very possibly fail on some phones too.